# NULL pointer exception with HTML Unit

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, htmlunit

I am using htmlunit-2/.9 version and when I try to get the current HTML Page content and save it to temp file for my future reference, I'm getting a null pointer exception when I invoke `currentPage.asXml()`.

Any pointer or help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at **com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.SgmlPage.asXml(SgmlPage.java:206)**
    at com.yahoo.vis.ddbuilder.validator.DDBuilderValidator.validateTemplate_1(DDBuilderValidator.java:308)
    at com.yahoo.vis.ddbuilder.validator.DDBuilderValidator.validate(DDBuilderValidator.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.yahoo.robot.components.interfaces.Executable.run(Executable.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Below is the Code snippet which is causing NULL Pointer. I am running this test for around 100 test cases, out of 100 it will randomly fails for 20-30 cases

```
private IValidationResponse validateTemplate_2(String url, Properties verifyProps, HtmlPage currentPage) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException
    {
        IValidationResponse validationResponse = new DefaultValidationResponse();
        String query = verifyProps.getProperty(IConstants.QUERY);
        System.err.println("Verifying Query ::- "+query);
        validationResponse.setQuery(query);
        validationResponse.setActualResponseAsBuffer(new StringBuffer(currentPage.asXml()));
...

}
```

Comment: Can you add code of `currentPage.asXml()`

Comment: currentPage is object of HtmlPage which is HTMLUnit class. asXml() is API of HtmlUnit

Comment: Please read FAQ section for better usage of SO. It will also help for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The [`HtmlPage`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html) extends [`SgmlPage`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/SgmlPage.html) class and I have gone through source code of `SgmlPage` for [`asXml()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit/2.9/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/SgmlPage.java#SgmlPage.asXml%28%29).

It internally calls another method `getDocumentElement()` which returns `DomElement`

[From Source Code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit/2.9/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/SgmlPage.java#SgmlPage.getDocumentElement%28%29), These are the methods :

```
 @Override
   public String asXml() {
       return getDocumentElement().asXml(); // This is Line 206, From your error trace
   }

public DomElement  getDocumentElement() {
        DomNode childNode = getFirstChild();

        while (childNode != null && !(childNode instanceof DomElement)) {

           childNode = childNode.getNextSibling();

       }
       return (DomElement) childNode;
}
```

Here There are chances that `childNode`  can be NULL. If  `childNode` is returned NULL,  calling `getDocumentElement().asXml();` will throw `NullPointerException`.

**PS.:** You haven't provided any details how you are calling method an what content you are passing. So, I can not help to find root cause But, I hope this will help you understanding at least Why you are getting the error.